# Why do we compare at most 7 points in closest pair algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

So, if within **δ * 2δ** rectangle R, we only need to compare one point from the left side to 7 points on the right side. What I don't understand is, despite reading the proof, inside R we can fill as many points as we want inside the rectangle which may exceed the total number of 7. Imagine if we have δ = 2, a point p(1.2, 1.1) on the left side, and on the right side, we have a whole bunch of q, such as q(1.5, 1.7) , q(1.4, 1.3),.....how can only comparing 7 points detects the closest pair? I thought that we must compare every points within rectangle R if it is the case. Please help me.

Comment: Can we have a link to "the proof?"

Comment: I don't think this question is out of place here, but you might get better answers on the Math site: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You can look at Introduction to Algorithm at Google Books: http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&printsec=frontcover&hl=vi&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=closest%20pair&f=false

Comment: Check out the links in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5757833/527152). They provide a pretty good reference. In particular [Figure 33.11 from Introduction to Algorithms](http://books.google.com/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&lpg=PA957&ots=BwVsGG7kFb&pg=PA960#v=onepage&q&f=true).

Comment: I read that and still unclear about 7 points stuff. I can fill it infinite number points in the delta zone to create infinite number of pairs which has value less than delta. I must be missing something here.

Comment: To address your point specifically, the distance between `q(1.5,1.7)` and `q(1.4,1.3)` is less than `δ`, which is impossible by construction of `δ`.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for your comment. I got it. Check my comment in Mig's answer if you're interest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There may only be 6 points inside your rectangle, since that's the maximum number of points that you can put in a rectangle with sides δ and 2δ maintaining the property that they are at least δ distant from each other.

The way to lay those 6 points is shown in the figure below:

[image: How to lay 6 points \delta apart from each other in a δ × 2δ rectangle]

You can check for yourself that there's way of putting another point inside the rectangle without violating the distance property. If you add more than 6 points, they would be less than δ apart, which is a contradiction, since δ is supposed to be the distance between the closest pair.

Since there may be a maximum of 6 points, testing 7 will guarantee that you find the solution.

I got figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFB4r.png) from [these UCSB slides](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ClosestPair.pdf), which may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks. With your simple explanation, it clears thing up a bit. However, in the slides, it is said that "How many point can be inside R if each pair is at least \delta apart"? And the answer in the slides is 6 `inside` R, not at the boundary of R.

Comment: @Amumu Yes, but they really mean "inside or right on the border". You should accept the answer if you think it is good enough. =)

Comment: Sure, but the only confusion left is the 7 points constant. I mean, I can't put an infinite number of points inside R to create infinite pairs which have less than \delta distance. Infinite may be too much, but if I have about 20 points with less than \delta distance, how can it make sense just to test 7 points?

Comment: Suddenly I got it. All the pair inside R must be delta apart, because if it is less than delta, that pair must delta itself. This means a contradiction, because delta is supposed to be the smallest distance prior to this final step, which means our algorithm in finding delta is faulty in the actual implementation. If you add this, I will mark as correct answer. Damn, this hidden knowledge costs me quite a time to figure it out.

Comment: @Amumu Exactly! I added a brief explanation about the contradiction part for future reference.